# Proving or disproving a mathematical argument

Tags: functions, logarithms

I have to either prove or disprove a mathematical argument:
$$ \log(f(n)) = o(\log(g(n))\rightarrow f(n) = o(g(n))$$

---

$small-o$ is an asymptotic notation that is explained below. (the $o$ that appears in the inequality). So, using the definition of $small-o$, this is what I principally have to prove:

$$\log(f(n)) < c \cdot \log(g(n))\rightarrow f(n) < c\cdot g(n)$$

$f(n), g(n)$ are functions that determine the growth in runtime for an input $n$, due to that $n$ is positive. (Computer science stuff, data algorithms and structures)

$c \in \mathbb{R}$, and $c>0$, and the $\log$ is in base $2$.

---

There is an asymptotic notation called ***small-o*** that goes as follows:
if we want to prove $f=o(g)$, (f,g are two input functions as described above) we have to show:
$$o = \{ f\mid  \exists c\in\mathbb{R}, c>0, \exists n_{0}\in \mathbb{N}, \forall n>n_{0} \mid f<c\cdot g\}$$

in our case, it is given.

I can say there is $c>0, c\in \mathbb{R}$, and there is $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, so for every $n>n_{0}$:
$$\log(f(n)) < c \cdot \log(g(n))$$

---

Yet, I stuggle to either prove, or disprove this argument.
I tried to use logarithmic rules in order to simplify it into something else, but it didn't really work as expected. If it is, by any chance, not a correct argument, what stance I should use in order to disprove it? Will a negative example be enough?

Comment: Counterexamples are sufficient to disprove a statement. In general if $a<b$ and $f(x)$ is strictly monotone increasing then $f(a)<f(b)$. Can you see how that's relevant to your problem?

Comment: $log(f(n)), log(g(n))$ are strictly monotone increasing functions, that will mean $f(n)<g(n)$ , with $c$ being equal to one ?

Comment: Think about what $log$ does to power functions...

Comment: If we take a logarithm of a number, we undo an exponentiation. $f(n), g(n)$ are not necessarily power functions no? they could be logarithmic functions for example. I don't quite understand the thought process behind it.

Comment: You can get the right font and spacing for $\log$ using `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: The logarithm is monotone increasing and so is its inverse, the exponential. You can also use properties of $\log$ like $\log x^y = y \log x$ as suggested by @DavidP

Comment: Some assumptions on $f$ and $g$ are necessary, for example that $f(n)$ tends to infinity.

Comment: So:
Let there be $f(n), g(n)$ montone strictly increasing functions. It is given that $c>0$ exists, and $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ exists, that for every $n>n_{0}$:  $$log(f(n)) < c \cdot log(g(n))$$. In order to prove the latter is also true we have to find a $c' > 0, n_{0}' \in \mathbb{N}$, so for every $n > n_{0}'$: $$f(n)<c' \cdot g(n)$$. So using the logarithm rule $log(x^{y}) = ylog(x)$ we get $$log(f(n)) < log((g(n)^{c})$$. We know that these two functions are also strictly monotone-increasing so we can say $$f(n)<(g(n)^c)$$, and for $n_{0}'=1, c'=1$ this inequality is true.

Comment: This is obviously not true, take $f(n) = n^2$ and $g(n) = n$ for a very straightforward counterexample.